# Problems with NAD27 projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have some data that is in NAD27, but I am having a hard time displaying it in QGIS.  I think that the problem is with the CRS.  I cannot seem to find the correct NAD27 option.  The closest one seems to be EPSG:2027 (NAD27(76)/UTM zone 15N), but my data points are still about 25 meters off.

This data plots up just fine in ArcGIS, and I have transformed it to NAD83, which I can use with no problem in QGIS, but this is an awkward workaround, and I would like to migrate this project into QGIS entirely.  Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Just to clarify - your x and y values are in decimal degrees?
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4267/

Comment: They are not...they're given to me in meters.   Does that mean that they've already been transformed?  I'm actually a bit confused on this point.  Also, I notice that there are no NAD27 systems here (http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=NAD27) that cover my study area, which is in South Louisiana.

Comment: NAD27 is actually a datum, not a projection. If you look at the info for EPSG:4267, it only defines a spheroid and how many radians are in a degree. If your data is in feet or meters, it has been projected.

South Louisiana State Plane is a possibility, although it uses feet, not meters. (That sounds like something an oil company would do). But you could easily change the units. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26782/

Answer (score 4):

The offset of 25 metres is an accuracy matter. The NAD27 CRS uses a different ellipsoid position than NAD83 or WGS84. The difference is normally given by +towgs84 values in QGIS. In early days, a rough 3-parameter or 7-parameter Helmert transformation was made to shift the data correctly.

Your first guess, EPSG:2027 is defined in QGIS with

`+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=clrk66 +units=m +no_defs`

In this definition, no shift (+towgs84) parameters are used at all. Try as a better solution:

EPSG:26715 `+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs`

The `+datum=NAD27` option uses a ntv2-grid for high accuracy.

Comment: Gosh, I didn't know this. When did QGIS start using grid-shift files by default? Is it only NAD27? N.

Comment: Actually, proj had it nearly from the start, 13 years ago: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/browser/trunk/proj/src/pj_datums.c?rev=848 and it is the only one incorporated by default: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/browser/trunk/proj/src/pj_datums.c . You might guess why...