# Incorrect coordinates when reprojecting NAD27 to NAD83

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, datum, nad83

I have some historic UTM coordinates as NAD27 (556787, 7169250) which I entered into a spreadsheet and have imported into QGIS.

I assign them the projection Nad27 / UTM zone 12N (EPSG: 26712)

I save as... Projection Nad 83 /UTM zone 12N (EPSG: 26912)

When I compare coordinates, the coordinate shift is different than what I know it should be (in particular, there is no east-west component to the transformation), and when I use a separate NTV2 transform there is a shift of ~ 30m north, 50m west.

I have looked at [This help article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64041/experiencing-transformation-anomalies-when-performing-a-save-as-to-convert-coord) which involves projecting across UTM zones, which I am not doing.

and [This other help article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48914/problems-with-nad27-projection-in-qgis) which is solved by using a more robust version of the nad27 projection (EPSG: 26712 instead of  EPSG:2027) which I am already doing

Am I missing something very simple here?

I am running QGIS 1.8.0 on window

Comment: No idea where it should be, but see if you can find the NTv2 files. For Canada, you need Ntv2_0.gsb. If it's not there, output is 556784.65 7169444.17. With it, 556732.11 7169475.68.

Comment: You say "the coordinate shift is different than what I know it should be". How much is this shift exactly and how much you were expecting it?

Comment: mkennedy:  The new coordinates I obtain are 556784.65, 7169444.17, suggesting I don't have the gsb file.  The coordinates you give are what I was expecting.  I'm not familiar with gsb files in QGIS.  Is there any documentation you can point me to off the top of your head?

Ardit:  The shift was 194.17m North, 2.34m West.
**sorry about the double post.  I was not aware of the 5 minute edit limit.

Comment: Be aware that the difference between the ellipsoid of NAD27 ellipsoid and the one of NAD83 along the minor axis is 168.5 m and 69.4 along the major axis. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum

Comment: ok, but that doesn't tell you anything about the lat-long or UTM E/N shift...  When I use the Ntv2_0 application on the NRCAN website (http://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/ntv2.php) I obtain the same results as mkennedy, which is what it should be.  I'm just now having trouble getting the transformation tool to work importing the GSB file.

Comment: There's a bit of info at the bottom of this ticket: http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3099 and here's a [gis] Q and A which may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38984/how-to-reproject-a-raster-file-in-qgis-with-datum-transformation